# Having "broken" y-axis in Bokeh plot/figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to have a "broken" y-axis in a Bokeh figure/plot, so that values that stand out too much will not ruin the entire plot? In my case I am using `vbar`, but guess this has to do with the `figure` object.

E.g.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of version `0.12.14` there is no built-in broken axis capability in Bokeh. It might be possible to implement custom extension mapper and axis models for this, but it would not be trivial to do. To propose adding this functionality to Bokeh directly, make a [Github feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).